# jQuery camera slider video issues

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery Camera Slider to display images and a Vimeo video. You can see it [here](http://pattonnz.businesscatalyst.com).

I have three questions.

1. When the page loads the I get white circles flashing in the top of the slider, it looks like the pagination buttons and a loading icon. Why is this happening, can I stop it?
2. Once the page has loaded, if a pagination button is immediately clicked the slider stalls and locks up. I don't know why this happens.
3. The page loads, the slider scrolls through the images perfectly but once the video gets played the slider's automatic play function stops (pagination still works, just not automatically).

Any help with anyof these questions is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should check the browser console for errors...

Answer (score 1):

I could see the circles on my end, but the slider worked even when I clicked through the slides rapidly. A lot of errors in the console though...[image]
**Update**: Yes, it hangs! I think the errors in the console are responsible for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. Turn the elements off in CSS and then get them to load once the page is ready.

Reference the controls by their wrapper:

```
CSS
.camera_pag {
    display: none;
}
```

It is natural for plugins to override 'display: none' styles like these at the appropriate time, but in the event that this doesn't I suggest showing the controls using the plugin's 'onLoaded' callback function.

```
JS
jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({       
   /*/     /*sets the height */
    thumbnails: false,  //true will make thumbnails of the image appear on hovering over pagination dots
    pagination: true,
    onLoaded: function() {
        $(".camera_pag").show(); // or .fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, putting the video in the second position stopped the hanging problem. I don't know why this worked, but for now I have to go with it as the fix.